# pymongo how to insert csv file into mongodb

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a csv file "data.csv" with the below data :

[image: "data.csv"]

I am now, trying to upload this csv into MongoDB with the below code :

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path="/Users/xxxx/Desktop/" -- Filepath
os.chdir(path)
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('internal-xxx.xxx.ai:1234',
                     username='xxx',
                     password='xxx',
                     authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1')
db=client["dbname"]
-- Creating a new collection with name "collectionname"
db_c=db["collectionname"] 
x=db_c.count_documents({}) -- Since its new one the count will be empty

def csv_to_json(filename, header=None):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=header)
    return data.to_dict('records')

print(csv_to_json('inspector1.csv'))
-- Below is the print result 
# [{0: 'RAISED_BY', 1: 'RAISED_ON', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'C'}, 
#  {0: '32050', 1: '3/5/20', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '50'}, 
#  {0: '32217', 1: '3/5/20', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '6'}, 
#  {0: '46212', 1: '3/5/20', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '7'}, 
#  {0: '31871', 1: '3/5/20', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '6'}, 
#  {0: '32567', 1: '3/5/20', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '6'}]

db_c.insert_many(csv_to_json('inspector.csv'))

# Error encountered : InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was 0
```

I think the issue is because of the conversion of csv into json, why do i get 0:,1:,2:, etc..in front of all the data elements.
Can you guys help me in sorting this one ?
Basically i wanted to insert my csv files into Mongo DB ?

Comment: Have you considered the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#mongoimport) tool?

Comment: Thx, but i am looking for Python way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_csv()` is using the default pandas indexing. To get it to index based off the header use the `header=0` parameter; in your case the change would be:

```
db_c.insert_many(csv_to_json('inspector.csv', header=0))
```